# Using Splitfolders without separating certain images

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two directories of medical images (cases and non cases) and I wanted to use split-folder to divide them into train/test/val sets.

Once complication: some images belong to the same patient, and I don't want them to be split in different sets. If two images belong to the same patient, the first 25 letters of their filename are the same. So I guessed this is what the option `group prefix` was for and used the code:

```
splitfolders.ratio(working_dir, output= working_dir + "WORKING_DIRS/", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, .1, .1), group_prefix=25)
```

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The length of pairs has to be equal. Coudn't find 24 matches for (namefile).png. Found 35 matches.
```

I have read the documentation on https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/ and I am not sure on how to interpret it. Does it mean that if for each patient I have 2 images, I have to set `group_prefix=2`? And if for some patient I have 2 and for some I have 3?
​

Comment: I think "The length of pairs has to be equal." makes it unusable for you, because you have a different amount of images for each patient, but the module assumes, that the amount is always the same. I recommend not using `split-folders` and programming it yourself. If I am correct, then you only need to split your images, like you did using the `ratio` keyword argument. In case your images are not in the same directory, you can use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: Makes sense, I will do so. Thank you!